# Singular homology groups of $S^5 - t^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $t^2 \subset S^5$ be a homeomorph of the two torus $T^2$.
How can we compute the homology groups $H_* (S^5-t^2;\mathbb{Z})$?

I know how to compute $H_* (S^5-s;\mathbb{Z})$ if $s$ is a homeomorph
of $S^1$, but I don't see if we can conclude from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Alexander duality***: If K is a compact, locally contractible, nonempty, proper subspace of $S^n$ , then $\widetilde{H_i}(S^n-K;\mathbb Z)= \widetilde{H}^{n-i-1}(K;\mathbb Z)$ for all $i $.

So from this it follows that

$H_0(S^5-T^2)=\mathbb Z$(since it is path connected),

$H_1(S^5-T^2)= H^3(T^2)=0$,

$H_2(S^5-t^2)=H^2(T^2)=\mathbb Z$,

$H_3(S^5-T^2)=H^1(T^2)=\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$ and

$H_k(S^5-T^2)=0$ for $k\geq 4$.

Comment: Why do you deal with $H_0$ separately? $\tilde{H}_0(S^5 \setminus T^2) = H^4(T^2) = 0$ hence $H_0(S^5 \setminus T^2) = \mathbb{Z}$, isn't it?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes I could write that too, but I just gave another explanation :)